# Passing data from View to Controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, binding

I get data from URL in controller but i need it dynamically

```
d3.json("http://localhost:2016/get_stats_for?brand_name="+$scope.brand,function(data))
```

i want to get $scope.brand from textBox in the view

how could i do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT 2**
Alternatively, you can use `ng-change` instead.

```js
app.controller('MyController', function($scope, MyService){
   $scope.brand = 'D&G'; //initialize value
   $scope.onBrandChange = function(){
       MyService.getByBrand($scope.brand).then(function(res){
           var result = res.data; //here is your JSON
       });
   });
});

app.service('MyService', function($http){
    this.getByBrand = function(brand){
        var URL = "http://localhost:2016/get_stats_forbrand_name="+brand;
        return $http.get(URL);
    };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
<input type='text' ng-change='onBrandChange()' ng-model-options="{debounce: 100}" ng-model='brand'></input>
</div>
```

---

You want to track changes to the variable from the scope?

```js
$scope.$watch('brand', function(newValue, oldValue){
   //fetch the json file
});
```

add the following to the ng-model element on the view

`ng-model-options="{debounce: 100}"`

The update will occur only if element was unchanged for more than 100ms (so in case of fast typing browser won't be throttled by multiple fetch requests)

Comment: i have a url with condition and value
this value need to set from a textbox in view.html